# How to run a script on server?

Tags: scripting, joomla

The defualt charset for all the datebase tables is swedish3_latin_ci
I want to change it to utf8_unicode_ci
I have found a script called phoca which can automatically change all the collations to utf8
How can I run the script?

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Might help if you read the [instructions](http://www.phoca.cz/documents/38-tools/154-how-to-change-collation-in-database) first.  Unzip and copy the folder to your server. Point your web browser to the index.php file inside the folder (i.e., http://yourdomain.com/folder/index.php). The PHP script will request your database information and execute the code to change the database. What the instructions don't mention is to make sure you back up the database before you run the script.